# How to Stop repeat Database in Android?

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I m new in android. here i make simple service.which is auto refresh after 5 min. but problem is that database upload repeated every time. So help me.... And in my code single string upload every time but i wont to make `JSONArray`. So help me out how to make `JSONArray` in my code.....

```
public class One extends Service {
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5*60*1000;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private Timer timer = null;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        if(timer != null)
        {
            timer.cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            timer = new Timer();
        }
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new DisplayTime(),0,NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

    class DisplayTime extends TimerTask
    {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    recll();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"run",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
        private void recll() {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                    final String body = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                    final String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                    final String date = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")).toString();
                    Date date1 = new Date(Long.valueOf(date));
                    final String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type")).toString();

                    final String fDate = date1.toString();

                    cursor.moveToNext();

                    class getSMSDetails extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(Void... params)
                        {
                            HashMap<String,String> param = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            param.put(Connect.KEY_NUMBER,number);
                            param.put(Connect.KEY_TYPE,type);
                            param.put(Connect.KEY_DATE,fDate);
                            param.put(Connect.KEY_BODY,body);

                            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                            String res = rh.sendPostRequest(Connect.URL_ADD, param);
                            return res;
                        }
                    }

                    getSMSDetails idata = new getSMSDetails();
                    idata.execute();
                }
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

here is my PHP code.....here i have requirement of enter 7 days data from entry time and whenever new entry comes i want enter new entry while it enters whole data again so i want to prevent duplicate entry thanks in advance....

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   //Getting values
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $dates = $_POST['date'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $start = strtotime("-7 days");
    $date = strtotime($dates);
    $end = strtotime("now");

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM message_detail where number =   '$number' and type = '$type' and date = '$date' and content = '$content'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) 
    {
        echo "already exist";
    }
    elseif($start <= $date &&  $end >= $date)
    {
        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO message_detail (number,type,date,content) VALUES   ('$number','$type','$date','$content')";
    } 
    //Importing our db connection script
    require_once('connect.php');

    //Executing query to database
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo 'Entry Added Successfully';
    }else{
        echo 'Could Not Add Entry';
    }
    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

connection.php

```
<?php

//Defining Constants
define('HOST','mysql.hostinger.in');
define('USER','u336100496_hiren');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','u336100496_sebu');

//Connecting to Database
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
?>
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the PHP code as well if you actually want any help

Comment: thanks for your response @RiggsFolly sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your connection require to the top of your script.

Where it was you were executing the first query without a connection so it would always fails and therefore take the ELSE that inserts a new row

Also you are running the INSERT in the wrong place it should be in the ELSEIF

```
<?php 
//Importing our db connection script
require_once('connect.php');

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
   //Getting values
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $dates = $_POST['date'];
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $start = strtotime("-7 days");
    $date = strtotime($dates);
    $end = strtotime("now");

    $query=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
                              FROM message_detail 
                              where number = '$number' 
                                and type = '$type' 
                                and date = '$date' 
                                and content = '$content'");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {
        echo "already exist";
    }
    elseif($start <= $date &&  $end >= $date) {
        //Creating an sql query
        $sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO message_detail (number,type,date,content) VALUES   ('$number','$type','$date','$content')";

        //Executing query to database
        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
            echo 'Entry Added Successfully';
        }else{
            echo 'Could Not Add Entry';
        }

    } 

    //Closing the database 
    mysqli_close($con);
}
```

Comment: in php logcat it's giving warning  mysqli_query(): Empty query

Comment: You had better add the code for `connect.php` to your question

Comment: without changes require_once('connect.php'); logcat of php <b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in <b>/home/u336100496/public_html/message_detail/insert.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in <b>/home/u336100496/public_html/message_detail/insert.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_query(): Empty query in <b>/home/u336100496/public_html/message_detail/insert.php</b> on line <b>29</b><br />
Could Not Add Entry<br />

Comment: here for enter only 7 days data is working fine problem is preventing duplicate entry

Comment: So your connection is failing **show me your `connection.php` script**. Edit your question to add it

Comment: You are getting a Duplicate Entry because the **first query is failing** therefore the `if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0) {` is running the `ELSEIF`

Comment: Have you looked at your Error log, if its a live server the PHP errors and the Apache errors all get logged together sometimes. CHECK YOUR LOGS

Comment: as pr my requirement i have to go for if elseif loop suggest any other solution if you have that satisfy the requirement

Comment: Just spotted something. You were running the update query outside the ELSEIF, see amendment

Comment: sorry i didn't get you will you plz describe more you may go programatically